# R get value at minimum and maximum time of day

Tags: r, data.table

I have some data that I need to analyse easily. I want to create a graph of the average usage per day of a week. The data is in a `data.table` with the following structure:

```
               time       value
2014-10-22 23:59:54   7433033.0
2014-10-23 00:00:12   7433034.0
2014-10-23 00:00:31   7433035.0
2014-10-23 00:00:49   7433036.0
...
2014-10-23 23:59:21   7443032.0
2014-10-23 23:59:40   7443033.0
2014-10-23 23:59:59   7443034.0
2014-10-24 00:00:19   7443035.0
```

Since the value is cumulative, I would need the maximum value of a day, minus the minimum value of that day, and then average all the values with the same days.

I already know how to get the day of the week (using [`as.POSIXlt`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/DateTimeClasses.html) and `$wday`). So how can I get the daily difference? Once I have the data in a structure like:

```
dayOfWeek  value
        0     10
        1     20
        2     50
```

I should be able to find the `mean` myself using some functions.

Here is a sample:

```
library(data.table)
data <- fread("http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=GXGiCAiu", header=T)
#get the difference per day

#create average per day of week
```

Comment: Could you provide a small reproducible example data set? Also, maybe you want to tag this with `data.table`, in case there's some faster way to do it taking advantage of that package.

Comment: If you already have the day of week. try `data[, .(value2=diff(value))]` for the daily difference.

Comment: @plafort If you look at the time column of the excerpt of data, you'll see that there are multiple measures per day.

Comment: @Frank OP states that they were able to summarize the data already. Their summary example shows the data broken up into separate days. They requested a list of differences in the value column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a trickier problem than it seemed at first glance. I think you need *two* separate aggregations, one to aggregate the cumulative usage values within each calendar day by taking the difference of the range, and then a second to aggregate the per-calendar-day usage values by weekday. You can extract the weekday with [`weekdays()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/weekday.POSIXt.html), calculate the daily difference with [`diff()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/diff.html) on the [`range()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/range.html), calculate the mean with [`mean()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/mean.html), and aggregate with [`aggregate()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/aggregate.html):

```
set.seed(1);
N <- as.integer(60*60*24/19*14);
df <- data.frame(time=seq(as.POSIXct('2014-10-23 00:00:12',tz='UTC'),by=19,length.out=N)+rnorm(N,0,0.5), value=seq(7433034,by=1,length.out=N)+rnorm(N,0,0.5) );
head(df);
##                  time   value
## 1 2014-10-23 00:00:11 7433034
## 2 2014-10-23 00:00:31 7433035
## 3 2014-10-23 00:00:49 7433036
## 4 2014-10-23 00:01:09 7433037
## 5 2014-10-23 00:01:28 7433039
## 6 2014-10-23 00:01:46 7433039
tail(df);
##                      time   value
## 63658 2014-11-05 23:58:14 7496691
## 63659 2014-11-05 23:58:33 7496692
## 63660 2014-11-05 23:58:51 7496693
## 63661 2014-11-05 23:59:11 7496694
## 63662 2014-11-05 23:59:31 7496695
## 63663 2014-11-05 23:59:49 7496697
df2 <- aggregate(value~date,cbind(df,date=as.Date(df$time)),function(x) diff(range(x)));
df2;
##          date    value
## 1  2014-10-23 4547.581
## 2  2014-10-24 4546.679
## 3  2014-10-25 4546.410
## 4  2014-10-26 4545.726
## 5  2014-10-27 4546.602
## 6  2014-10-28 4545.194
## 7  2014-10-29 4546.136
## 8  2014-10-30 4546.454
## 9  2014-10-31 4545.712
## 10 2014-11-01 4546.901
## 11 2014-11-02 4544.684
## 12 2014-11-03 4546.378
## 13 2014-11-04 4547.061
## 14 2014-11-05 4547.082
df3 <- aggregate(value~dayOfWeek,cbind(df2,dayOfWeek=weekdays(df2$date)),mean);
df3;
##   dayOfWeek    value
## 1    Friday 4546.196
## 2    Monday 4546.490
## 3  Saturday 4546.656
## 4    Sunday 4545.205
## 5  Thursday 4547.018
## 6   Tuesday 4546.128
## 7 Wednesday 4546.609
```

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways to do this with R. You can use `ave` from base R or `data.table` or `dplyr` packages. These solutions all add the summaries as columns of your data.

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(dayOfWeek = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L), 
                 value = c(10L, 5L, 20L, 60L, 50L))
```

#### base r

```
df$min <- ave(df$value, df$dayOfWeek, FUN = min)
df$max <- ave(df$value, df$dayOfWeek, FUN = max)
```

#### data.table

```
require(data.table)
setDT(df)[, ":="(min = min(value), max = max(value)), by = dayOfWeek][]
```

#### dplyr

```
require(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(dayOfWeek) %>% mutate(min = min(value), max = max(value))
```

If you just want the summaries, you can also use the following:

```
# base
aggregate(value~dayOfWeek, df, FUN = min)
aggregate(value~dayOfWeek, df, FUN = max)
# data.table
setDT(df)[, list(min = min(value), max = max(value)), by = dayOfWeek]
# dplyr
df %>% group_by(dayOfWeek) %>% summarise(min(value), max(value))
```

Comment: The only question mark in the OP is in "So how can I get the daily difference?" to which the answer seems to be `diff(range(x))`, right? Anyways, nice answer for teaching me what `ave` is for :) Also, the OP starts with a `data.table`, not a `data.frame`.

Answer (score 1):

Came across this looking for something else.  I think you were looking for the difference and mean per Monday, Tuesday, etc. Sticking with data.table allows a quick all in one call to get the mean per day of week and the difference per day of the week.  This gives an output of 7 rows and three columns.

```
library(data.table)
data <- fread("http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=GXGiCAiu", header=T)

data_summary <- data[,list(mean = mean(value),
                           diff = max(value)-min(value)),
                     by = list(date = format(as.POSIXct(time), format = "%A"))]
```

This gives an output of 7 rows and three columns.

```
        date    mean   diff
1:  Thursday 7470107 166966
2:    Friday 7445945   6119
3:  Saturday 7550000 100000
4:    Sunday 7550000 100000
5:    Monday 7550000 100000
6:   Tuesday 7550000 100000
7: Wednesday 7550000 100000
```